# Export mesh with weights and vertex groups

Tags: export, weight-painting, vertex-groups

Is there any way to export a mesh that contains weights and vertex groups? I tried exporting a mesh that contains such properties as an .obj but it didn't keep the weights and groups. So is there any file that supports these or is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Obj is a pure mesh file format. It can do some other tricks too. Documented is curve data for example. But animation, including vertex groups and weigth paints is not part of it. Try FBX. But that's also no guarantee that everything will arrive like you have it in Blender. It heavily depends of the target software and what you want to do.

Comment: Tried exporting it as an .FBX, still no luck. But thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: So, what is your target platform, and what are you trying to do here? Maybe there's another way :)

Comment: Essentially I have downloaded approximately 172 Halo 5 models, 86 helmets 86 body armour. These weren't waited when I downloaded them, so I have been going through the grueling task of weighting them. From here I wanted a way to be able to store these assets so that I could import them into a later blender project when I need them. Creating a library of sorts for myself.

Comment: I see. So it's not an export to a game engine. But a library for Blender. Forget about external file formats. When you need it in Blender anyways, then you could simply save the whole thing as a *.blend file. And append the needed things from there then. The append menu item can be found in the File menu :)

Comment: Ah perfect! That should work just fine :) Thanks for the advice.